# If a belongs to A does that mean a exists or that |A|>0? Empty sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If i say "If f:A->B is onto and b belongs to B, then the number of solutions x that belong to A  for the equation f(x)=b can be:) (0,1,2,3 and infinity are the options).

Does b e B => E b e B, don't be mad for me using e for belongs to and E for exists. And if b e B => E b e B => |B|>0. But that would also mean |A|>0 so we just circle all solutions but 0.

Maybe I got confused on the concept of an empty set. An empty set isn't nothing, although sometimes we see it that way, It's a set with 0 elements. If b e B doesn't mean that B exists then the only way you could express that b e B is by saying b is nothing. But how do you express that in notation?

How do I say if nothing is in set B then B is an empty set.

Comment: By the definition of *onto*, since $f$ is onto, there exists at least one element $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Comment: Yes, if $a \in A$ we have that set $A$ has *at least* one element and thus the number of elements of $A$ is not $0$, i.e. $|A| > 0$. At the same time, saying that $A$ has (at least) one element means that $A$ is not *empty* i.e. $A \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @user2661923 but what if we suppose that both sets are empty. The "function" input would be f()=  it will just be a blank nothingness. a function from an empty set into an empty set. It is a function since if we have (x,y) e f and (x,z) then y=z but there is no x or z or y. So it's vacuously true. No?

Comment: You're _given_ that $b\in B$, so $B$ is **not** empty. (Hence $f$ surjective implies that $A$ is non-empty as well).

Comment: Why did i get a down vote? What for?

Comment: I agree with the comment of @DavidC.Ullrich.  I would have worded it: "If f:A->B is onto and b belongs to B...".  This means that you are asking the mathSE reviewer to assume that B contains the element b.

Comment: As far as your posting being downvoted, although I understand the downvote, I disagree with it.  On one side of the ledger, there is no quality control on mathSE reviewers downvoting a question.  On the other side of the ledger, it seems as if your posting *rambled*, and that you did not proofread your posting.  Going forward, if you wish to have mathSE reviewers react positively to your future postings, see [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things can get confusing when the word "nothing" comes into play, huh?

According to most mathematicians, the value of a variable is always something that exists. In other words, if I have some variable $b$, then the value of $b$ has to be something; it can't be nothing. Furthermore, the value of $b$ exists; it can't be something nonexistent.

The statement $b \in B$ (that is, $b$ belongs to $B$) does, in fact, imply that $\exists b, b \in B$ (that is, there is some thing $b$ such that $b$ belongs to $B$). And this, in turn, implies that $|B| > 0$ (the cardinality of the set $B$ is greater than $0$).

So, the statement $b \in B$, all by itself, implies that $B$ is not the empty set, even though we don't really know anything about $b$.

There might be some mathematical texts in which variables can equal nothing, or in which a variable can have a value which is nonexistent. But I'm not aware of any such texts. Doing math that way would probably be very confusing.

> How do I say if nothing is in set B then B is an empty set.

Remember that the English word "nothing" is a special word which indicates that the sentence has some kind of meaning of "there does not exist …." In this case, I would write that as:

$$(\neg \exists x, x \in B) \implies B = \emptyset.$$